# A way to make trees in NavMesh, with terrain URP

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I make trees in unity, URP, but also having NavMesh, you see, I have trees, but leaves, touching the ground make the NavMesh, include areas around the tree to be non walkable, how can I create trees, mass place them in terrain, and have them work with NavMesh?

Comment: create tree mesh and rebuild navMesh? because navMesh is detect by mesh

Answer (score 0):

You could place planes/quads under/near trees and mark them with whichever navmesh type you want them to be (walkable etc). And bake navmesh again.

Comment: how would i do that